# What causes facet errors after Hibernate Search upgrade from version 4 to 5?

Tags: exception, migration, hibernate-search, facet

Since upgrading (described below) the Facet search throws this exception.

> HSEARCH000268: Facet request 'groupArchiv' tries to facet on  field
> 'facetfieldarchiv'  which either does not exists or is not configured
> for faceting (via @Facet). Check your configuration.

Migrating from hibernate.search.version 4.4.4 to hibernate.search.version 5.5.2

lucene-queryparser 5.3.1

jdk 1.8xx

All the Indexing is via a `ClassBridge`.

The field `facetfieldarchiv` is in the index.

All other searches are working fine.

```
protected List<FacetBean> searchFacets(String searchQuery, String defaultField, 
                                    String onField, String facetGroupName)
{
     
    List<FacetBean> results = new ArrayList<FacetBean>();
    FullTextSession ftSession = getHibernateFulltextSession();
    org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer analyzer = getAnalyzer(Archiv.class);
    QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(defaultField, analyzer);
    try
    {

        Query query = parser.parse(searchQuery);
        QueryBuilder builder = ftSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Item.class).get();

        FacetingRequest gruppeFacetingRequest = builder.facet()
                        .name(facetGroupName)
                        .onField(onField).discrete()
                        .orderedBy(FacetSortOrder.COUNT_DESC)
                        .includeZeroCounts(false)
                        .maxFacetCount(99999)
                        .createFacetingRequest();

        org.hibernate.search.FullTextQuery hibQuery = ftSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Item.class);
        FacetManager facetManager = hibQuery.getFacetManager();
        facetManager.enableFaceting(gruppeFacetingRequest);
        Iterator<Facet> itf1 = facetManager.getFacets(facetGroupName).iterator();
      
       **// The error occurs here,** 


        while (itf1.hasNext())
        {

            FacetBean bean = new FacetBean();
            Facet facetgruppe = itf1.next();
            bean.setFacetName(facetgruppe.getFacetingName());
            bean.setFacetFieldName(facetgruppe.getFieldName());
            bean.setFacetValue(facetgruppe.getValue());
            bean.setFacetCount(facetgruppe.getCount());

            results.add(bean);
        }

    } catch (Exception e)
    {

        logger.error(" Fehler FacetSuche:   " + e);
    }
    
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Did you check the @Facet annotation like the error message suggests? http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/migrate/5.3/

Answer (score 3):

The faceting API went through an overhaul between Hibernate Search 4 and 5. In the 4.x series one could facet on any (single valued) field without special configuration. The implementation was based on a custom `Collector`.

In Hibernate Search 5.x the implementation has changed and native Lucene faceting support is used. For this to work though, the faceted fields need to be known at index time. For this the annotation `@Facet` got introduced which needs to be places on fields used for faceting. You find more information in the Hibernate Search online docs or check this [blog post](http://in.relation.to/2015/05/11/hibernate-search-530-beta-1-with-native-lucene-faceting/) which gives you a short summary of the changes.

Comment: What help me: the faceted fields need to be known at index time

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  for answering.
I didn't catch that change since 5.x 
My facets are made up of several fields.
Is there a possibility to build the facets in a ClassBridge using pur Lucene?
like

```
FacetField f = new FacetField(fieldName, fieldValue);
document.add(f);
indexWriter.addDocument(document);
```

Thank you
pe